# How list every item of dir(object)?

Tags: python

In Python, to find all attributes, there is:

```
dir(object)

object.__dict__.keys()
```

But what i want is to list what is in the second branch, not only the first branch, it's kind of a recursive operation?

How to do that?

it's like

```
dir(dir(x) for x in dir(math))
```

tried this and still get the same result duplicated:

```
>>> for i in dir(math):
...     for j in i:
...         print dir(j)
```

and all results are the methods of `str`

Update: it seems that the `dir()` commande returns a list of `str`, here is a simple hack; I tried to exclude the `reserved names` to see if i go further, but the result was only `str`

```
[i for i in dir(math) if i[0]!="_"]

[type(i) for i in dir(math) if i[0]!="_"]
```

Thank you again :)

Comment: 'list what is in the second branch' - what do you mean by a *branch* here?

Comment: make dir() for every method in this object

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp: You will hit an infinite recursion error. It's objects all the way down.

Comment: I think you may have an XY problem here. Are you sure `vars` is not more along the lines of what you need?

Comment: @MartijnPieters this is because inheritance?
inspectorG4dget dont understand?

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp: `dir()` lists attributes, many of which are methods. Methods have methods, which have the same methods, ad infinitum. It's like the world on top of the turtle. From there it's [turtles *all the way down*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down).

Comment: @MartijnPieters so this is why it scans only the first branch?

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp: `dir()` lists attribute names only. If you want the associated values too, use `vars()`. But no method will list attribute names and values recursively, no.

Comment: i thought it is like an iterator that stops after finding an error.

Comment: Iterators do not stop on exceptions, only on `StopIteration`, which is specifically designed for that role.

Comment: @Lattyware so i guss there is  nothing to raise this error to stop the  recursion!

Answer (score 3):

```
object.__dict__.keys()   # Just keys
object.__dict__.values() # Just values
object.__dict__.items()  # Key-value pairs
```

**Edit** wait! I think I misunderstood. You want to list an object's properties, and those properties' properties and so on and so forth? Try something like this:

```
def discover(object):
    for key in dir(object):
        value = getattr(object, key)
        print key, value
        discover(value)
```

It's pretty crude, but that's the recursion I think you're looking for. Note that you will have to stop it manually at some point. There's no turtles at the bottom, it goes on and on.

Comment: why i get errors? AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__dict__'

Comment: This is one reason to use `dir()` and `vars()` or `inspect` over manually accessing `__dict__`. The error occurs because built-in functions don't have `__dict__`.

Comment: I modified the example to use `dir()`

Comment: on windows, it seems  that it reaches the max depth fast! i get the error: `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

Comment: What's "fast"? In time or in steps? It's `depth-first search`, it will hit the limit before doing anything useful :) as I said, it's a crude example

Comment: so i take this answer since it is not possible, i'll update the question showing another problem

Comment: I think you should post another question, and give this one closure